# Can test users be verified? Can they have usernames?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

I'm working on an app where I'd like to be able to do things with a user's Facebook username.  I know that I can get this through the basic user object, but I'm worried about the case where the user doesn't have a FB username when they register with my site/application, but does gets one later.  The question is how to test this with FB test users:

- A user (a regular user, anyway) has to be verified before they can get a username.  Is it possible to verify test users?
- If so, is it then possible to give a test user a username?
- Is it possible to change that username as part of the testing process (on the chance that my code doesn't work perfectly the first time :)?

What I'm thinking of doing is setting up a realtime subscription on "username", which I've established is possible.  If the user above suddenly gets a username, my app gets notified and I can do whatever I do with it.  But that implies that a lot of other things are possible, which they may not be.  I could retrieve and check the user object on login and keep updating the fields, but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.  Any advice out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot claim usernames for test users.  You will have to use your own account or test with a real fake account, which Facebook frowns upon.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought / was afraid of.  Thanks!