# Can facebook test users be verified?

Tags: python, facebook, unit-testing

It seems someone has asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101847/can-test-users-be-verified-can-they-have-usernames) before. However it is focus on the username, which I don't care about.

I have added a real email address to my test user and confirmed it by clicking on the verification email. However the test user is still marked as unverified.

This is a big problem when unit testing with test users.

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
me = graph.get_object("me")
if 'verified' not in me or not me['verified']:
    return False
```

I can't pass this line in my unit test, since test users are always unverified.

Any advice please?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user: _“Someone is considered verified if they take any of the following actions: - Register for mobile - Confirm their account via SMS - Enter a valid credit card”_ … so simply confirming an email address does not even qualify as a “verified” criterion according to this.

Comment: Interesting.  Is there a way to see if the email was verified? Can a user sign up with facebook with a fake email address or email address of a friend? I need to be sure my users are not impersonating someone else and have access to the given email.

Comment: If you get an email back from the API, it should be confirmed by the user already. (But you will not get an email address for every user.)

Comment: When I signed up for Facebook it was 2007. Not sure how its done these days. Upon signup is the user forced to confirm the email before getting access to use facebook in first place? If thats true, I am sorted.

Comment: No, I don’t think that’s the case. But, again – the user does not necessarily even have an email address on file with FB, so don’t rely on getting one to use in your app in the first place.

Comment: very true. Thanks for confirming this. You can put this as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user:

> Someone is considered verified if they take any of the following actions:
>   - Register for mobile
>   - Confirm their account via SMS
>   - Enter a valid credit card

… so simply confirming an email address does not even qualify as a “verified” criterion according to this.

If you do get an email back from the API, it should be confirmed by the user already. (Otherwise FB will not give it out in the first place.)

But you will not get an email address for every user. The user does not necessarily even have an email address on file with FB, so don’t rely on getting one to use in your app in the first place.